# How to used a shared transition from RecyclerView to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I've seen this questioned asked a number of times on here without an answer. I'm hoping if I ask it again maybe someone will be kind enough to help me with it.

I'm trying to implement a shared transition from an Item in a Recyclerview to a fragment.

I currently have my fragment transaction in the onBindView method of the adapter.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    activity.getSupportFragmentMnager().beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(v, "SharedString")
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment2)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

In the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addsharedelement), addSharedElement(view and string) confuse me. How do I give the view a unique ID and should I even be using v here?

Can the string be what ever I want?

Comment: The string is the `android:transitionName="` of the view that the provided view is supposed to morph into. The `v` argument is passed to retrieve the `android:transitionName="` for back navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is my implementation. There is `FragmentList` with `RecyclerView` with images on each item. And there is `FragmentDetail` with only on big image. Image from `FragmentList` list item fly to `FragmentDetail`. `TransitionName` of animated view on `FragmentList` and  `FragmentDetail` must be same. So I give unique transition name for each list item ImageView:

`imageView.setTransitionName("anyString" + position)`

Then I pass that string to `FragmentDetail` via `setArguments` and set big image `transitionName` to that string. Also we should provide `Transition` which describes how view from one view hierarchy animates to another viewhierarchy. After that we should pass that `transition` to fragment. I do it before `FragmentTransaction`:

```
 detailFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(getTransition());
 detailFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(getTransition());
```

Or you can override `getSharedElementEnterTransition` and `getSharedElementReturnTransition` of `Fragment` and declare `transition` there. Here is full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentList())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void showDetail(View view) {
        String transitionName = view.getTransitionName();

        FragmentDetail fragment = new FragmentDetail();
        fragment.setArguments(FragmentDetail.getBundle(transitionName));
        fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(getTransition());
        fragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(getTransition());

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .addSharedElement(view, transitionName)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    private Transition getTransition() {
        TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
        set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
        set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
        set.addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
        set.addTransition(new ChangeTransform());
        return set;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

FragmentList:

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        rv.setAdapter(new ListAdapter());
        return view;
    }

    private class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return new Holder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Holder hold = (Holder) holder;
            hold.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showDetail(hold.imageView);
            });
            //unique string for each list item
            hold.imageView.setTransitionName("anyString" + position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        private class Holder extends ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;

            public Holder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

FragmentDetail:

```
public class FragmentDetail extends Fragment {
    private static final String NAME_KEY = "key";

    public static Bundle getBundle(String transitionName) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(NAME_KEY, transitionName);
        return args;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        String transitionName = getArguments().getString(NAME_KEY);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setTransitionName(transitionName);
        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment_detail.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cat"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cat"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is result:

[image]

`TransitionName` may be any string you want. 
There is `ViewCompat.setTransitionName` if you need support pre Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [ashakirov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492694/7118726):

### Problem

> Return Transition was not working!

Reason:
On `popbackstack` from `Fragment B` to `Fragment A`, `Fragment A's` onCreateView is called and if your data is still loading then the return transition won't work with only ashakirov's code.

### Solution

> Postpone the transition in your fragments

Add this line where the loading starts in your `fragment A`:

```
postponeEnterTransition();
```

After your data is loaded or you've set your adapter, write this:

```
startPostponedEnterTransition();
```

This ensures that your transition only happens after your data is loaded.
Also, make sure you start the transition even in 'data failed to load scenarios'.

If you want to postpone the transition in your `fragment B` when going from `A to B` then add this to your `fragment B`:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //hold the transition
        postponeEnterTransition();
        //when the views are available then start the transition
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                startPostponedEnterTransition();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```