# setSharedElementReturnTransition doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, animation, kotlin, fragment

I'm trying to implement shared view animation between fragments. Anything works fine except `setSharedElementReturnTransition()`. When I press the back button animation doesn't work.

```
        val transition = TransitionInflater
        .from(requireContext())
        .inflateTransition(R.transition.view_transition)
    sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
    sharedElementReturnTransition = transition
```

Also here is my transition xml file:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeBounds/>
</transitionSet>
```

It looks weird because enter animation works well.

Comment: put space before / like `<changeBounds />`

Comment: check this answer. There is example with shared elements animation between fragments.  `setSharedElementReturnTransition` method there works perfect https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492694/1372866