# Android - RecyclerView image gallery on image selection zoom in animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, image-gallery

[Wanted animation example GIF](https://gifyu.com/image/SN54g)

I have a similar image gallery made with a RecyclerView. I want to replicate this image selection animation which scales to center of screen starting from its position

I'm not sure how to perform this animation. I thought about creating a copy in the same screen position and then make the scaling animation, but this ImageView is inside the RecyclerView and the position I'm getting is wrong

At this point I'm totally lost.

this is what i was trying:

```
                val imageView = ImageView(activity.applicationContext)
            activity.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root).addView(imageView)

            val location = IntArray(2)
            holder.itemView.getLocationOnScreen(location)
            val posX = location[0]
            val poxY = location[1]

            imageView.x = posX + 0f
            imageView.y = poxY + 0f

            imageView.layoutParams.height = holder.itemView.height
            imageView.layoutParams.width = holder.itemView.width
```

RESULT:

[image: 2]

It almost fits the position

Comment: Follow this https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom

Answer (score 1):

there are many way to achieve animation like this

> maybe you can open new `activity` with animation

https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity

> Enlarge a view using a zoom animation

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom

> also you can use latest motion animation

https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion

Comment: I got what I wanted with zoom animation. Motion animation looks interesting, ill have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This animation called "shared element transition". Check for example [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492694/1372866)  or [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate)